# Javascript: Dynamic form checkboxes validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Context:

Dynamic form i.e. where questions are fetched from a database and I can't assume anything from what `id` or `name` the element will get (it will have something to do with the database id of the entry).

### Problem:

Have to check if at least one `checkbox` per group is checked. How can I do this with Javascript or jQuery when i'm getting names like:

```
event_form[q_6][0]
event_form[q_6][1]
event_form[q_6][2]
event_form[q_6][3]
event_form[q_6][4]
event_form[q_6][5]
event_form[q_6][6]
```

where `[q_i]`refers to the checkbox group and `[i]` to the value/option. And as I said, I can't know before hand that `q_6`will be a checkbox question, it could be a simple text input.

I thought I could use a regex solution but I don't know if it's the best way to go...

Answer (score 1):

You can select any elements that starts with a certain name, and is a checkbox

```
$('[name^="event_form\\[q_6\\]"][type="checkbox"]')
```

now to see if any of those are checked, you can do

```
$('[name^="event_form\\[q_6\\]"][type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')
```

Comment: It seems to be a possible solution but somehow it's matching with every input element. I don't understand the syntax enough to detect the error, could you check it? thanks